# Воспроизведение музыки при использовании другого приложения

Tags: swift, аудио, avfoundation

Всем привет!

Есть игра, в которой есть звук работающий через avFondation.
если во время игры свернуть ее и зайти в какое-то приложение, включить музыку, а потом вернуться к игре, то музыка ставится на паузу.

Нужно сделать так, что бы можно было играть под музыку с других музыкальных приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import AVFoundation

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```